# How to debug any file in node JS without specifying the file name in launch,json

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

[image: Check this image]

I want to debug both workout.js and test.js but vscode is debugging only the workout.js
how do I set the file name dynamic. so I can debug any js file with one launch.json config

Like

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/${currentFileName}.js",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) for details.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Node js",
            "program": "${file}",
            "request": "launch",
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
            "type": "node"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) about variable substitution in Debugging and Task configuration files, there are a few that can be used to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to add multiple settings inside your single lunch config file. and whenever you want to debug any then choose that name while debugging